# uninstalled tigervnc from ubuntu 20.04, now cannot start tightvnc

Tags: vnc, tightvncserver

I have been trying to get any vnc setup to work for me.. that issue is posted elsewhere.. but one issue in particular now has come up..

I installed and removed tigervnc, but now tightvncserver complains it cannot startup... how do I create a new xvnc-session?

inside myxvncserver:1.log

```
13/05/20 10:46:40 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
13/05/20 10:46:40 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
13/05/20 10:46:40 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
13/05/20 10:46:40 All Rights Reserved.
13/05/20 10:46:40 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
13/05/20 10:46:40 Desktop name 'X' (2600k:1)
13/05/20 10:46:40 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
13/05/20 10:46:40 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
/etc/X11/Xvnc-session: 6: vncconfig: not found
Killing Xtightvnc process ID 17651
~                                                                                                                                                               
~                                                                                                                                                               
~
```

I searched elsewhere and someone states "oh just get a new xvnc-session" since tigervnc apparently deletes it (thanks tigervnc)

how do I fix this, so I can connect to ubuntu 20.04 via my mac?

Comment: You can use ssh and X11 forwarding to connect to your Linux machine from your mac

Comment: ive reinstalled the entire OS... forwarding X was not working from Mac

Comment: Is X12 forwarding enabled in your SSH configuration? See this article for how to setup and use X11:https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/11035-how-to-use-x11-forwarding.html

Comment: Please post the output of `head -n6 /etc/X11/Xvnc-session|tail -n1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `sudo apt purge tigervnc-standalone-server`

What I believe is happening is that you deinstalled the tigervnc-standalone-server package but you did not purge it, thus leaving its configuration such as /etc/X11/Xvnc-session and others installed and active.

Comment: i lost patience and just reinstalled the OS, but will give you a check for answering with something very likely .. I indeed didn't purge

Comment: This fixed the exact same issue for me after I'd been struggling with it all afternoon. I had removed tigervnc-standalone-server, but it left /etc/X11/Xvnc-session in place, and that turned out to be what was breaking tightvnc server. Probably could have just deleted that file, but the purge deleted it, and then tightvnc server started working again. Thanks.

Comment: Saved my life with this after I had a warning about a lock file on restart of a tightvnc service, removed the lock file, then service would not restart without an error from gnome-session-binary.